# Specifying schema update options for BigQueryIO in Apache Beam

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Is it possible to specify the schema options for BigQueryIO in Apache Beam? Afaik one is normally able to use `com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.JobConfigurationLoad` to specify the the schema should be updated when new fields are inserted to a table using:

```
JobConfigurationLoad loadConfig = new JobConfigurationLoad();
..
loadConfig.setSchemaUpdateOptions(Arrays.asList("ALLOW_FIELD_ADDITION", "ALLOW_FIELD_RELAXATION"));
```

But how can I specify this using the `BigQueryIO` class in Apache Beam? I'm using Apache Beam SDK 2.1.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beam currently doesn't support this out of the box. There is already [a feature request](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-876) filed for this. It should be pretty easy to implement (contributions welcome :) ) but I don't think anyone is actively working on it right now.