# How to specify bigquery schema in apache beam bigqueryIO (typescript sdk)

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

While creating an Apache beam pipeline to `readFromPubsub` and `writeToBigquery` using TypeScript SDK, I'm getting an error that says;

```bash
Error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The input doesn't has a schema
```

I can't find a way to specify input schema with TypScript SDK. The documentation also doesn't provide any info.

[This is how we can specify schema with Python and Java SDK.](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/built-in/google-bigquery/#writing-to-a-table)

Sample code that gives error:

```js
import * as beam from "apache-beam";
import * as bigqueryio from "apache-beam/io/bigqueryio";

export function createPipeline() {
  // A pipeline is simply a callable that takes a root object.
  return async (root: beam.Root) => {
    const pcollection = await root.applyAsync(
      beam.readFromPubSub({
        topic: "projects/PROJECT_NAME/topics/TOPIC_NAME",
      })
    );

    const resultColl = pcollection.applyAsync(
      bigqueryio.writeToBigQuery("PROJECT_NAME:DATASET.TABLE_NAME", {
        createDisposition: "Never",
      })
    );
  };
}
```

bigqueryio.[writeToBigQuery(...)](https://beam.apache.org/releases/typedoc/current/functions/io_bigqueryio.writeToBigQuery.html) doesn't have a schema input parameter.
Also, according to docs, the schema is not mandatory when putting `createDisposition: "Never"`.

Is there any other way to specify the schema with typescript or how to fix this issue?

Here is complete error log:

```bash
...
Tearing down sdks:java:io:google-cloud-platform:expansion-service:shadowJar.
/home/mitanshu/Desktop/playground/beam-starter-typescript/node_modules/apache-beam/dist/src/apache_beam/transforms/external.js:173
                throw new Error(response.error);
                      ^

Error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The input doesn't has a schema
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:141)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryIO$Write.expandTyped(BigQueryIO.java:3241)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryIO$Write.expand(BigQueryIO.java:3223)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryIO$Write.expand(BigQueryIO.java:2174)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.applyInternal(Pipeline.java:545)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.applyTransform(Pipeline.java:479)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollection.apply(PCollection.java:352)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQuerySchemaIOProvider$BigQuerySchemaIO$2.expand(BigQuerySchemaIOProvider.java:231)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQuerySchemaIOProvider$BigQuerySchemaIO$2.expand(BigQuerySchemaIOProvider.java:193)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.applyInternal(Pipeline.java:545)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.applyTransform(Pipeline.java:496)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.expansion.service.ExpansionService$TransformProvider.apply(ExpansionService.java:402)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.expansion.service.ExpansionService.expand(ExpansionService.java:555)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.expansion.service.ExpansionService.expand(ExpansionService.java:639)
        at org.apache.beam.model.expansion.v1.ExpansionServiceGrpc$MethodHandlers.invoke(ExpansionServiceGrpc.java:306)
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p54p0.io.grpc.stub.ServerCalls$UnaryServerCallHandler$UnaryServerCallListener.onHalfClose(ServerCalls.java:182)
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p54p0.io.grpc.internal.ServerCallImpl$ServerStreamListenerImpl.halfClosed(ServerCallImpl.java:355)
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p54p0.io.grpc.internal.ServerImpl$JumpToApplicationThreadServerStreamListener$1HalfClosed.runInContext(ServerImpl.java:867)
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p54p0.io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37)
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p54p0.io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:133)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)

    at RawExternalTransform.expandInternalAsync (/home/mitanshu/Desktop/playground/beam-starter-typescript/node_modules/apache-beam/dist/src/apache_beam/transforms/external.js:173:23)
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async Pipeline.applyAsyncTransform (/home/mitanshu/Desktop/playground/beam-starter-typescript/node_modules/apache-beam/dist/src/apache_beam/internal/pipeline.js:202:22)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Mitanshu, have you checked this [stack link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47247013/specifying-schema-update-options-for-bigqueryio-in-apache-beam) ? is this helpful for you ?

Comment: that's related to 'schema update' with Java SDK.

Comment: It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new GCP [support case](https://cloud.google.com/support/). Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the [issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) describing your issue.